# Running sinlge line of javascript code?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The following is the problem I'm having.  I've been working with php, and that's all well and good. The problem I am having is with JavaScript. My mentor helped me get a JavaScript set up to do the work in the background, so that's not my problem. I am so unlearned in JavaScript as to not even know to run the command in the below segment. The JS code has been implemented with an  tag as the href, so I know it works, just not how to apply it here.

```
 <?php           

        if (isset($_GET['item'])) { ** This way it is dependent on them having created a product and the add page redirecting them with all required info to pop up the edit form. **

?>   

            ** This is the section I have the problem with... No idea how to implement the following correctly. **

            <script>

                openEditItemForm(<?php echo $_GET['item'] ?>);

            </script>

 <?php

        } else{

            }

?>
```

Sorry if this seems to be a rather ridiculous question, but as I said I have had extremely little exposure to JS and have no idea how to even find what I'm looking for in searches.

Edit:
Okay, so I kinda left this open ended what this was for... This is a back-end section where my client will be adding items to his website. The "openEditItemForm" is defined elsewhere and has worked at another point on the page. This isn't my problem. My problem on this section is actually having the code run when the page is reopened and the url contains the item identity. After having changed the code to what was recommended with the json_encode and so forth, it is still not completing the function it was created to do.

Also, thank you Rick Burgess for the explanation as to why to include the json_encode and to Brad and steveukx for the updated code.

Again, I'm lost when it comes to this, so I may be looking for the wrong deal again. That code is supposed to open a dialog box with an edit form in the box. Works elsewhere on the page in another form (as noted above in the href section of an < a > tag). Am I expecting something that won't happen?

Second Edit: Okay, so what I overlooked was that the function that I was trying to get to work already worked... The coding the the guys below provided helped immensely. Works like a charm. It now calls the dialog once the customer inputs an item identifier. Awesome!

Comment: Looks like your calling a function `openEditForm` with the parameter of the php item..is that function defined anywhere?

Comment: You have a serious XSS vulnerability in your code!  Use this instead:  `openEditItemForm(<?php echo json_encode($_GET['item']);?>);`

Comment: As you appear to be a junior programmer its worth explaining a little bit about what XSS vulnerability you have. You are getting a variable from the query string and placing that directly in the mark-up, think about what would happen if someone submitted something like:

");alert('this website sucks'" it would be inserted directly and executed, resulting in a alert on your page, now that is a extremely tame example but you get the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$_GET['item']` is a string, you will need to wrap it in quotes to prevent causing a JavaScript error:

```
<script>
    openEditItemForm("<?php echo $_GET['item'] ?>");
</script>
```

It's worth noting that this would be a security vulnerability, and you should make sure that the value is validated before printing it into the document.

As Brad has commented, the minimum that should be applied to the user content would be `json_encode`:

```
openEditItemForm("<?php echo json_encode($_GET['item']) ?>");
```

Comment: NO!  Don't do this!  This code is wide open to XSS attacks.  Use `json_encode()` instead!

Comment: Thanks, I was adding that as an edit while you were commenting.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am getting at.  No matter what data you are injecting into JavaScript, validated or not, you should `json_encode()` it.  Simply adding a note that you need to validate the data does not fix all problems.

Comment: A non-persistent XSS, that would be annoying, but not really dangerous as it has no server access.

Comment: You haven't seen the rest of the codebase for this project, we have no way of knowing if this is persistent or not, this could be part of a function that generates a cached page for other users. its better to always protect yourself rather than risk overlooking something that may become an issue in the future

Comment: @RickBurgess - true dat. user input should be sanitized, and as a sidenote, if JSON is'nt what you're looking for, [FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) would work just as well for this. I was just pointing out that based on the given code, it's not really dangerous as much as it could lead to links to your own site with spam and annoying popups.

Comment: Wow... Okay, so I'm a bit of a Nimrod. I overlooked an error on my part. That bit of code works perfect! Thanks to everyone who commented.